# After uninstalling all Nuget packages, build fails because it can't find project.assets.json file

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I uninstalled all Nuget packages from our project and linked directly to the dlls instead since we cannot install Nuget packages on our network or our build server.

After I did this and everything compiles locally, I moved to the build server and tried to compile, but I get this error:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.405\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'c:\Projects\Gui\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

Why is the build recognizing a package dependency and how is this resolved?

Comment: have you tried running dotnet restore, even if you are not using any package?

Comment: Maybe you have a nuget.config with a *packageSources*-entry, that isn't accessible from the build server, but from your local machine? (Please see the [MS's error description page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1004) (last point))

Comment: I did run a dotnet restore and I no longer have a nuget.config file.  It was removed because I don't have Nuget packages in the solution any more.  Neither of these worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not get around the absence of a project.assets.json file.  I had two options:

- Check the obj folder into git so that it was there when the build was run.
- Run a dotnet restore as part of the build script.

I went with option 2 and added the call to dotnet restore as part of the build script so that our git repository stayed clean.